# Fit Gaussian Function Plot

Tags: plotting

These are my data, x data are in Log,and i want to find their gaussian function fit.Can someone help me to have thier Gaussian plot?

```
data={{1/100000,4.58557*10^-5}, {1/10000,4.58043*10^-4}, {1/1000, 0.00452954}, {1/100,0.0238797}, {1/10,0.10114}, {1,0.0619271}, {10,0.00823958}}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). Please [edit] your question and explain what have you tried, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Your data does not look like a Gaussian. However if you take the Log of x and y it resembles more a Gaussian.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{1/100000, 4.58557*10^-5}, {1/10000, 4.58043*10^-4}, {1/1000, 
0.00452954}, {1/100, 0.0238797}, {1/10, 0.10114}, {1, 
0.0619271}, {10, 0.00823958}};
data1 = Transpose[{Log[data[[All, 1]]], data[[All, 2]]}];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data1, a Exp[-(x - b)^2/(2*c^2)], {a, b, c}, x]
Show[{ListPlot[data1, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[nlm // Normal, {x, -12, 6}]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Extract and plot the residuals:

```
 nlm["FitResiduals"]
 ListPlot[%, Filling -> Axis](*Nice plot*)
```